# Reading multiple files into separate data frames

Tags: python, import, blob, xlsx

I found this method on stack :

```
import glob
d = {}
for filename in glob.glob('*.xlsx'):
    d[filename[:-4]] = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name = 'Bilan')
```

How do I change that to have the name of all of my dataframe more like :

-df1

-df2

-df3

...

-dfN

and so on. The name based on the filename is nice but tedious to code with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably do something like this:

```
import glob
d = {}
base_name = "df{}"
flag = 0

for filename in glob.glob('*.xlsx'):
    d[base_name.format(flag)] = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name = 'Bilan')
    flag += 1
```

Here you create a `base_name` for your name and a `flag` to track the position of your file and then use those variables to construct a full filename.

Comment: But when I try to df.head(), it tell me the dataframe doesn't exist ?

Comment: You can actually also try using `enumerate` instead of the flag like `for counter, filename in enumerate(glob.glob('*.xlsx')):` but I'm not sure it will work with this datatype